# .NET C# - How to sanitize the required error messages from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

I have a question as regards to the handling of error messages in a form which I created.
Whenever the user doesn't fill out the information will be stored in here `ModelState.Root.Children`.

To iterate through every item/errorMessage, I firstly do a check if there is a sum of errors and then I proceed to access every string that corresponds to a field.

This is my public class for the viewmodel of my page.
What I have achieved so far is to pass every error message to a List so that afterwards I can be able to print it out on a popup window on my front-end side.

```cs
public class LandingViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Introduce un nombre.")]
    public string ContactFormName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Introduce un correo.")]
    public string ContactFormEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Introduce un teléfono de contacto.")]
    public string ContactFormTel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Introduce un teléfono de contacto.")]
    public string Reason { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Confirma la política de privacidad para enviar la solicitud.")]
    public bool ContactoPolitica { get; set; }

    public string ContactFormText { get; set; }
}
```

This my public class for creating the base response which will contain a status and a message to send over to the front-end side, it will possibly contain every error message if there is one.

```cs
public class BaseResponse
{
 public string status { get; set; }
 public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly, here is my `HttpPost` which is fired through an AJAX request I have on my page.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<BaseResponse> Landing(LandingViewModel model)
{
    string result = await registerService.SendEmailForContactLanding(model);
    var response = new BaseResponse();
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && ModelState.ErrorCount == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, result);
            response.status = "KO";
            response.message = "No se ha podido enviar tu solicitud. Por favor, intentelo más tarde.";
        }

        string[] errors;

        if (ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
        {
            List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in ModelState.Root.Children)
            {

                var errorMessage = item.Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
                errorMessages.Add(errorMessage);

            }
            // in here I will transform the List<string> to a response.message for my front-end
        }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            response.status = "OK";
            response.message = "Tu petición se ha enviado correctamente.";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response = new BaseResponse();
        response.status = "KO";
        response.message = "Ha habido un error con tu petición " + ex.Message;
    }

    return response;
}
```

What I want to get rid of is this: whenever the user doesn't fill out some of the fields, while I pass through the breakpoints, the error messages don't appear as are being written on my `public class LandingViewModel`.

For example,  `[Display(Name = "Introduce un nombre.")]` would have to appear as **"Introduce un nombre."** but it does not. It appears like: **"The Introduce un teléfono de contacto. field is required."**

**The field is required** for some reason is being thrown inside every error message string. How is it possible to sanitize this kind of messages ?

Comment: Why not specify a required error message? `[Required(ErrorMessage = "A phone number is required.")]`

Comment: Alright, I thought it wasn't possible to do it that way. Thanks for your help. It actually works out with that manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing my `ViewModel` to this, it worked. I'm getting the error messages exactly as I wanted.

```cs
public class LandingViewModel
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Introduce un nombre.")]
    public string ContactFormName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Introduce un correo.")]
    public string ContactFormEmail { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Introduce un teléfono de contacto.")]
    public string ContactFormTel { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecciona la razón de contacto.")]
    public string Reason { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirma la política de privacidad para enviar la solicitud.")]
    public bool ContactoPolitica { get; set; }

    public string ContactFormText { get; set; }

}
```